# 時系列の特徴量の作成の仕方

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

機械学習における、時系列の特徴量作成に関して質問です。

以下の添付した画像から、例えば

・Morning直後はある値が増加傾向にある。
・NoonもMorningと比べて大きな変化量はないが、増加傾向にある。
・Eveningも大きな変化量はないが、増加傾向にある。

こういった事実現象を時系列の特徴量として、表現するにはどういった方法がありますでしょうか
機械学習に精通している皆様方、ぜひご指導のほど宜しくお願いいたします。

[image: ある信号値]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

機械学習については初心者ですが、質問の中にある以下の分析であれば、統計学のうち記述統計を使った従来のデータ分析で可能です。

> - Morning直後はある値が増加傾向にある。
> - NoonもMorningと比べて大きな変化量はないが、増加傾向にある。
> - Eveningも大きな変化量はないが、増加傾向にある。

増加傾向を分析したのであれば、時系列の差分（階差）を使うのが向いています。

機械学習が得意なことは、「集めたデータからデータの特徴を学習してモデル化し、そのモデルを使って未来の新しいデータを予測したり、分類したりすること」といわれています。今回のケースであれば、異常検知や将来予測ではないかと思います。

異常検知をする場合、時系列の差分（階差）が時系列の特徴量の一つとして使えないことはないとは思いますが、異常データがどういうものかわからなければ、何が時系列の特徴量として適切なのかは判断できないと思います。「特徴量」という前に、機械学習で何をしたいのか、そのためにはどういう手法を使うのかということをハッキリさせた方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

まだ閉じていない質問のようなので

まずは時刻だと思いますが、２つのグラフだけでもパターンが異なるので曜日や対象の分野での特性（月曜日が休み、火曜日が機器の入れ替え、、、）が特徴量になるかと思います。

これが繰り返されているのであれば特徴量抽出して機械学習にかけるよりもARIMAなどの時系列モデルにかけた方がよいかもしれません。